# In Android how do you get an activity to continually listen for a message from a server?

Tags: android, listener

I've tried searching around and I can't find a good answer that makes sense.

Basically when the activity first starts it should connect to a server and continually listen for a message. When it gets it, it'll parse it and if it's a particular message, close the connection and then do some other stuff. I should also be able to close it if the user pushes a button.

I tried searching around and I honestly can't tell if I should use servlets or services or what (edit: or how to use them). I do know that it probably needs to be on it's own thread.

So what should I use?

Edit: I'm not sure how to use the servers/services/etc. to make it happen

Comment: Would you want to use push notifications?

Comment: Push notifications? You mean those things that pop up even when the app isn't on? No. It only needs to display when the app is on screen.

Comment: @user2312638 push notifications could still be a simple way to go, as you can simply throw them away if the app isn't open... They're fast, and a bit more reliable given how fickle a cellular data connection can be.

Comment: It's not just a message to be displayed, if it gets a certain message it should close all threads and finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

An [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is what you're gonna want. It's the easiest to implement and it's perfect for network operations. It automatically handles running the service in its own thread. Once you establish a connection with the server, it should stay open until you respond with some message from the server.

Comment: ok but how do I handle the code for listening to the input of the server and then closing the service?

Comment: @user2312638 Of course not. You have to imeplement all network operations yourself. One option is to use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. I couldn't find a way to handle the inputstream

Comment: InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
String result ="";
while (result.equals(""))
{          result=convertStreamToString(in);
}

Comment: @user2312638 What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: The while loop never closes

Comment: And you're positive you're getting a response from the server?

Comment: pretty sure, perhaps I should just use a socket

Comment: @user2312638 Yes, it actually seems like what you're trying to do is best suited for establishing a TCP connection and then maintaining that connection as needed.

Comment: @user2312638 There seems to be a good amount of tutorials on Google. http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html seems like a pretty good one. A bunch of these parts you won't need. Is your server already set up to accept tcp connections? If not, you also need to learn how to set up your server to listen for TCP connections in whatever language you are using on your server.